# Noise background, how can I implement this?

Tags: html, css, image, background

Below is the background image I am working with. (it's just cropped this way so you guys can see)

[image]

I need this to cover the whole page of the site I am building. How should I implement this? Make it much darker and go with transparent pngs?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "how should I implement this". Are you aware of the background-repeat option in CSS? http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: @Aaron Newton, I thought because of the nature of my image there needed to be some sort of hack..looks like it works just fine with background repeat. I was under the impression that it would not tile properly. Everything works fine now, though. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why darker?

Did you want it to be your background image with repeating/tiling?

```
body
{
background-image:url('foo.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: Yes @p.campbell -- will that not show creases in the image, though?

Comment: @James Allardice, @p.campbell thanks guys it is working perfectly! Have a great day everyone.